# Wait ajax to complete before continue loop

Tags: multisite, ajax, users

I'm developing a code that searches for about 5000 orphaned users, and delete them. Using Ajax, how do I wait for a response to complete and then continue the loop?
Currently, the loop will keep executing and I have pending ajax call in the background that I think will hammer the server to process it at the same time.

Here is the sample code.

```
<script>
        var users_info = <?php echo json_encode($usersarray); ?>;
        console.log(users_info);
        $=jQuery;
        var each = '';
        j = 0;
        for ( i=0; i < users_info.length; i++) {
            each = users_info[i];
            var data = {
                'action': 'delete_orphan_users',
                'user_id': each
            };
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                $("#status").prepend(response);
                j++;
                $("#deletedusers").html(j);
            });
            if (j==users_info.length){
                alert('Finished');
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Why bother with ajax?  You have the $usersarray.  So just use a php loop.

Comment: See this topic! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320587/pause-jquery-ajax-script-until-script-returns-successfully/

Comment: @shanebp, I've tried that and it causes the page to time out. To solve that is to use ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified my codes based on Jory Hogeveen comments, and it solved my problem. What I do is, to not using the regular loop but instead use a recursive function that calls itself after it finishes calling for the request. For those who are looking for the same answer, please see below.

```
var users_info = <?php echo json_encode($usersarray); ?>;
console.log(users_info);
$=jQuery;
var each = '';
    j = 0;
    function nextAjax(i) {
        var data = {
            'action': 'delete_orphan_users',
            'user_id': users_info[i]
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            n = new Date($.now());
            m = n.getHours()+':'+n.getMinutes();
            $("#status").prepend(m+' '+response);
            j++;
            $("#deletedusers").html(j);
            if( j==users_info.lenght ){
                location.reload(); //current batch finished, reload screen to get another batch of users
            } else {
                nextAjax(j);
            }
        });
    }
    console.log('Start')
    nextAjax(j);
```